# How to add constraint to a list that is generated by a definite clause grammar?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to use definite clause grammars in prolog to accept strings of the form u,2,v where u and are strings of zeroes and ones. There is a constraint whereby the number of zeroes in 'u' must equal the number of ones in 'v'.

I can get the interpreter to accept strings of u,2,v but I'm having trouble adding the constraints.

```
s--> t,
{t(Input,[]),
 find_zeroes(Input,X),length(X,Z),
 reverse(Input,RevInput),find_ones(RevInput,Y),length(Y,Z)}.

t --> [2].
t --> l,[2],r.

l --> [X],{member(X,[0,1])}.
l --> [X],l,{member(X,[0,1])}.
r --> [Y],{member(Y,[0,1])}.
r --> [Y],r,{member(Y,[0,1])}.



accfindzeroes([H|T],Acc,Result):- H = 0, accfindzeroes(T,[H|Acc],Result).
accfindzeroes([H|T],Acc,Result):- H \= 0, accfindzeroes(T,Acc,Result).

accfindzeroes([2|_],Acc,Acc).
find_zeroes(List,Result):-accfindzeroes(List,[],Result).


accfindones([H|T],Acc,Result):-  H = 1, accfindones(T,[H|Acc],Result).
accfindones([H|T],Acc,Result):- H \= 1, accfindones(T,Acc,Result).

accfindones([2|_],Acc,Acc).
find_ones(List,Result):-accfindones(List,[],Result).
```

For example:

```
    ?- t([0,1,1,2,1,0,0],[]).
    True.
```

As required, but,

```
    ?- s([0,1,1,2,1,0,0],[]).
```

Loops infinitely...

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the second line but I don't know how to rectify it. I think the problem is 't' isn't outputting a list before attempting to resolve the constraints so it doesn't work but as I said I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724118/writing-dcg-for-strings-containing-same-number-of-specific-digits-prolog).

Comment: ah brilliant, thank you for the link!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing DCG for strings containing same number of specific digits - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724118/writing-dcg-for-strings-containing-same-number-of-specific-digits-prolog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724118/writing-dcg-for-strings-containing-same-number-of-specific-digits-prolog) question, but I have already written the code.

```
t --> [2].
t --> l(N),[2],r(N).

l(0) --> [].
l(N) --> [0],l(N0), { N is N0 + 1 }.
l(N) --> [1],l(N).

r(0) --> [].
r(N) --> [0],r(N).
r(N) --> [1],r(N0), { N is N0 + 1 }.
```

Your problem is that the call `t(Input,[])` just generates longer and longer sequences, without any connection to your input.